# onEdit() to move row to other sheet sometimes moves row below target row

Tags: google-apps-script

I've made an `onEdit()` function which moves the target row to another sheet based on the "Status" Column value. it seems to work fine... but sometimes at random moments the function runs when status column is changed and the row below the target row moves with it to the other sheet. I can't find where the problem comes from.

I can't seem to find a flaw in the code so I wondered if it could've something to do with the fact that multiple people are working in this sheet and some how the `getRowIndex()` get messed up.

```
 function onEdit(e) {

    var ss = e.source;
      var s = ss.getActiveSheet();
      var r = e.range;
       
      // where the action and move columns are in the form responses sheet
      var actionCol = 1;
      var nameCol = 1;
     
      // Get the row and column of the active cell.
      var rowIndex = r.getRowIndex();
      var colIndex = r.getColumnIndex();
    
       
      // Get the number of columns in the active sheet.
     
      var colNumber = s.getLastColumn();
       
      // if our action/status col is changed to Nieuw do stuff
      if (e.value == "Nieuw" && colIndex == actionCol) {
        // get our target sheet name - in this example we are using the priority column
        var targetSheet = s.getRange(rowIndex, nameCol).getValue();
        // if the sheet exists do more stuff
        if (ss.getSheetByName(targetSheet)) { 
          // set our target sheet and target range
          var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName(targetSheet);
          var targetRange = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow()+1, 1, 1, colNumber);
          // get our source range/row
          var sourceRange = s.getRange(rowIndex, 1, 1, colNumber);
         
          sourceRange.copyTo(targetRange);
         
          s.deleteRow(rowIndex);
          
        }
      }
}
```

Comment: Instead of getting a range for the target sheet, and using `copyTo()` use `sheet.appendRow(1D Array);`  https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#appendRow(Object)  Also, you should implement Lock Service because multiple people are using the spreadsheet.  `sheet.appendRow(1D Array);` is atomic, so Lock Service isn't needed for that, but getting the source range could be a problem with multiple users.  See https://stackoverflow.com/a/57022855/2946873

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of getting a range for the target sheet, and using `copyTo()` use `sheet.appendRow(1D Array);` https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/

Also, you should implement Lock Service because multiple people are using the spreadsheet. `sheet.appendRow(1D Array);` is atomic, so Lock Service isn't needed for that, but getting the source range could be a problem with multiple users. 
See [How do I use LockService properly every time in Google Apps Script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57017691)